# How to use variable in JQuery select

Tags: jquery

How do I modify the jquery to use the var instead of the '12'?

```
    var disableId = 12;

    if (e.currentTarget.checked) {

        $("input:checkbox[value=12]").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $("input:checkbox[value=12]").attr("disabled", false);
    }
```

Comment: $("input:checkbox[value='"+disableId +"']).attr("disabled", true);

Comment: In case you go straight to Anton's upvoted answer, I'll just point out here [what I've said in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21482280/1317805): the `if` statement you're using is unnecessary as you can simply pass in `e.currentTarget.checked` in place of `true` or `false`. You should also use `prop()` instead of `attr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jQuery's `prop()` method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr()` for boolean values; also there's no need for the IF statements at all as you can just set the `disabled` state to equal `e.currentTarget.checked` (which is either `true` or `false`):

```
var disableId = 12,
    state = e.currentTarget.checked;

$("input:checkbox[value='" + disableId + "']").prop("disabled", state);
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the string and add it

```
$("input:checkbox[value='"+disableId +"']").prop("disabled", true);
```

also you should use prop() instead of attr for boleean values